# Where does the C# generics naming convention come from?

Tags: c#, generics, naming-conventions

I understand `T` comes from `Type`, but why is it that the next variable often used is `K`?

Comment: Where have you seen this? I tend to use `T`, `U`, `V`.

Comment: Do you have an example? I often see `<TSomeValue, TSomethingElse>`

Comment: Most implementations I see of generics name them `T`, `K`

Comment: @Tim - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(VS.80).aspx, scroll down to "Multiple Generic Types"  In that case, K comes from "Key"

Comment: @Josh thanks. From the MSDN link: `public void AddHead(K key,T item)`

Comment: @Josh, @Tim Robinson: Do you see how `K` is being used for `Key` there? It's not a generic generic example (ha!).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've seen `K` used for `Key` but not frequently as the "next" type parameter. For example, you'll see

```
Dictionary<K, V>
```

where `K` is for `Key` and `V` is for `Value`.

Sometimes you'll see `T1`, `T2`, etc. or `T`, `U`, `V` (the former is preferred here). But I prefer more descriptive names like

```
Map<TSource, TDestination>
```

or

```
Create<TUnitOfWork>
```

Answer (score 2):

One more variation is the `GenericFunction<T1,T2,TResult>`, where TResult is the type of value returned by the functon. (as in, `Func<T1,T2,...,TResult>`)

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that it's from `Key`.