# what's the purpose of generic variable for defining generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I was reading the generics on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

we can define the simple generic class as follows using the `T for type`

```
class Generics<T> 
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        public void fun(T no1, T no2)
        {
            list.Add(no1);
        }
    }
```

Then I tried to use the different variable for type e.g. `X for type` as follows and it worked

```
class Generics<X> 
    {
        List<X> list = new List<X>();
        public void fun(X no1, X no2)
        {
            list.Add(no1);
        }
    }
```

I am **interested** to know that why C# allows us to use any variable for type and what are the advantage of this approach

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not variable just an alias for generic type just to make code more readable. Take a look at `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` - it's far more clear than `Dictionary<T, X>` would be.

Answer (score 3):

It's a convension to use `T`.

`T` for Type.

You could use `TOut` or `TIn` if it better described your intent, or `TWhatever`.

Have a look [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/94551/whats-a-good-naming-convention-for-generic-types-in-c) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367939/where-does-the-c-sharp-generics-naming-convention-come-from) for further info on Generics naming convensions.

> search?q=generics+naming+convension

Answer (score 2):

The reason for using a variable is that there can be multiple variable (type)s, and to difference between them they are named.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a name for the generic parameter, otherwise you can't refer to it. For example, how else could you write your fun(T no1, T no2) method? You can't use the name of the actual class (because you don't know what it is yet - that's why you're using generics!), but you need to refer to it in some way, so you assign a name that refers to the unknown class, in this case T.

As for why T is often used, it's just a convention - T stands for (t)ype. You can use anything you want though. Quite often when a class has multiple generic parameters you'll see them as e.g. GenericClass<T, U, V> and again that's just a convention based on carrying on alphabetically from T. Often you'll instead see more meaningful names, for example a generic dictionary class may be defined as Dictionary<TKey, TValue> to make is clearer what the types are being used for.

Answer (score 0):

T or X is just a representation of "Type" variable, you can use others as well as long as there is not  a known Type named as T or X.