# Where does the T, U, V convention for generic type params come from?

Tags: java, c#, scala, generics, programming-languages

Java, C#, and TypeScript (aka. the Sun/Hejlsberg family of languages) use `T`, `U`, `V`, etc. to represent generic type parameters. Ostensibly that's because `T` stands for "Type", and `U` and `V` follow `T` in the alphabet.

On the other hand, Scala uses `A`, `B`, `C` and so on, and OCaml and Haskell use `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Where do these conventions come from? Is it because the functional languages are closer to math proofs, where `α`, `β`, and `γ` are used by convention?

---

Similar, but doesn't answer my question: [Where does the C# generics naming convention come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367939/where-does-the-c-sharp-generics-naming-convention-come-from).

Comment: I believe it all began with `T`being a shorthand for Template (known from C++). However it´s impossible to answer that question here, that´s why I´m voting to close it.

Comment: I guess `T` stands for a *Type*, when `U`, `V` are just the next letters in English alphabet (when we want more than one generic)

Comment: On a map, it's often `<K,V>` for key, value. It depends of the semantic I guess.

Comment: java List, Set and Collections use <E>. I guess it stands for "Entry". So it looks like in java at least they tried to choose abbrevations of what the generic argument represents: Collection<E> for entry, Map<K,V> for key and value and Comparator<T> for type. EDIT: <E> seems to stand for "element" actually.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm hoping for a link to an old discussion/commit/mailing list where the convention was first discussed.

Comment: First StackOverflow isn´t a good place to ask for links and mailings to anything but a place to ask specific programming questions that show an actual problem. Anyway I guess that such a list doesn´t even exist, it just evolved by time.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS given the way [`E` is described in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), it is probably "element" rather than "entry".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the standard Java SE API's, the designer have typically chosen a one-letter identifier that is related to the meaning / purpose of the type parameter:

- `Iterator<T>` - [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) where `T` means type.  Other examples are `ListIterator<T>`, `Iterable<T>`, `Comparable<T>`, `Comparator<T>` and `Class<T>`.
- `Collection<E>` - [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) where `E` means element.  Various other collection classes and interfaces use `E`.
- `Map<K,V>` - [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) where `K` means key, and `V` means value.
- `Enum<E>` - [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) where `E` means enum.

These tend to disprove your assertion that there is a general (widespread) `T`, `U`, `V` convention, at least for Java.  Obviously, in the absence of specific guidance, some individual designers will adopt what is an obvious extension to the guidance to use `T` (see links below) but that would appear to be a result of individual choice.  (And the groups probably would have treated this as not worthy of discussion.)

(If you want to do an exhaustive search, visit each of the javadocs index A-Z pages, and search them for all occurrences of "<".)

---

> I'm hoping for a link to an old discussion/commit/mailing list where the convention was first discussed.

In the case of Java, I doubt that you will find this.  The discussions and mailing lists would have been private, and the Java source code was still closed when generics were added to the language, along with all of the examples above.

---

@Lew Bloch has found a few examples (see below) of `T`, `U`, `V` in the APIs added to Java SE in Java 8 as part of the streams support.  I assert that this does not prove a general pattern, and the large number of preexisting classes disprove it.

Other negative evidence of a general pattern or convention:

- [http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~alundblad/styleguide/index-v6.html#toc-type-variables](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Ealundblad/styleguide/index-v6.html#toc-type-variables) which doesn't mention `U` and `V`.
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html which recommends use of `S`, `U` and `V` as 2nd, 3rd and 4th type parameters.  (Not `U`, `V`, `W` ...)

Finally, the JLS ([JLS 6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1)) recommends:

> Type variable names should be pithy (single character if possible) yet evocative, and should not include lower case letters. This makes it easy to distinguish type parameters from ordinary classes and interfaces.
>
> Container types should use the name `E` for their element type. Maps should use `K` for the type of their keys and `V` for the type of their values. The name `X` should be used for arbitrary exception types. We use `T` for type, whenever there is not anything more specific about the type to distinguish it. (This is often the case in generic methods.)
>
> If there are multiple type parameters that denote arbitrary types, **one should use letters that neighbor `T` in the alphabet, such as `S`.** Alternately, **it is acceptable to use numeric subscripts (e.g., `T1`, `T2`)** to distinguish among the different type variables. In such cases, all the variables with the same prefix should be subscripted.

In short, `U` and `V` are not explicitly mentioned in the JLS, but other alternatives are.

Comment: "These tend to disprove your assertion that there is a T, U, V convention..." Except that there actually is such a convention. For the general case where there's no special semantic, use `T` _et seq._ For generics that have an element type, `E` is traditional. For key-value pairs, `K` and `V`. For other special semantics the letters can hint: `L` and `R` for "left" and "right", perhaps.

Comment: I'm talking about a convention to use letters in sequence starting with T ... as the OP is postulating.  Can you point out examples where the standard Java SE classes use >>that<< convention?

Comment: I was talking about `T`, `U`. `V` also. That's what _et seq._ means - "and what follows" in Latin. It's a standard abbreviation. I have seen `T`, `U`. `V` used in a lot of professional code. Have you read the Java Tutorial? It lists these ("`S`,`U`,`V` etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types", under "Type Parameter Naming Conventions") at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html. I recommend reading the documentation; it's most informative, @Stephen C.

Comment: Now, anyone could look these up, but you're welcome, I did the research for you. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html. And the wider community uses it, too. `FirstType<T, U>` in the examples at https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-generics-java-%E2%80%93-0. `Repository<T, U>` at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Generics. And many, many, many more ...