# Sonar S00119 rename generic name allows digits

Tags: java, generics, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have the following code

```
protected <TProperty> TProperty getPropertyFromConfig(SubConfiguration cfg,
        String property, TProperty defaultValue, Class<TProperty> clazz)
```

Which seems readable, but Sonar warns about generic name:

> ```
> Rename this generic name to match the regular expression '^[A-Z][0-9]?$'
> ```

But the description statement is about using a **single letter**

> Following the established convention of **single-letter type parameter** names helps users and maintainers

So it allows also a digit:

```
protected <T1> TProperty getPropertyFromConfig(SubConfiguration cfg,
        String property, T1 defaultValue, Class<T1> clazz)
```

Should it allows generic type name with digits?

**EDIT**

The duplicate questions/answers doesn't refer to adding digit to generic name

Comment: Some people like shorter code, i suppose. So Sonar adds in a rule to support this. You can turn off that rule if you don't like it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900933/10272286. A single number is probably allowed in the regex for sonarlint because other big libraries have used generics like `<T, T2, T3, T4>` etc with single digit numbers. I will see if I can find something to go into more depth about the numbering

Comment: @SizableShrimp my question is more about the added digit

Comment: @Sweeper  my question is more about the added digit rule allows

Comment: The third dupe addresses digits.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33394836/2513200) quotes the [google style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.8-type-variable-names), which allows digits: "A single capital letter, optionally followed by a single numeral (such as E, T, X, T2) "

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44589464/2513200) quotes the [JLS chapter 6.1. Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1) itself: "Alternately, it is acceptable to use numeric subscripts (e.g., T1, T2) to distinguish among the different type variables." this statement is still present in [the current version 11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1)